# Fatal error al intentar conectar a una base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes a todos,

Estaba programando un `plugin` para `wordpress` en lenguaje `PHP` para mi empresa, se trata de un formulario que recogerá los datos a una base de datos que tenemos en otro servidor distinto al de la web dentro de la empresa.

Este es mi código

```
$usuario = "root";
    $password = "****";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "logytel";   

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password);

    if (!$conexion) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    echo "Connected successfully";}

    $db = mysqli_select_db ($conexion, $basededatos) or die ("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Prueba_WEB";

    $resultado = mysqli_query ($conexion, $consulta) or die ("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

    mysqli_close ($conexion);
```

Y este el mensaje que resuelve, que no da ningún error concreto:

> El plugin no ha podido activarse porque ha provocado un error fatal.
>   No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos

Llevo bastantes horas con ello y no consigo el resultado, si alguien puede ayudar, lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Se me ocurre que esta mal el nombre de la bases de datos

Comment: Si es *“otro servidor distinto al de la web”* no debería ser `localhost`.

Comment: @Marcos @Sal Cambio el nombre del servidor de localhost al nombre de la máquina que aloja MySQL, en este caso, SQL2012.logytel.logytel.com y me sale este error:
`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin_prueba/Plugin_prueba.php on line 28
Connection failed: Connection refused`

Y si pongo su IP:
`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin_prueba/Plugin_prueba.php on line 28
Connection failed: Connection refused`

Comment: Si tienes acceso al otro servidor (donde están los datos), lo más simple es que programes en ese servidor una API a la cual le pidas los datos. Una API en este caso sería código PHP en el servidor que aloja los datos. Ese código recibe las peticiones por una URL y devuelve generalmente un JSON con los datos. Luego, desde Wordpress puedes usar Ajax para mandar a pedir los datos a la API. Es así como se suelen resolver este tipo de situaciones. Entiendo que al ser nueva te suene a chino, pero no es tan complicado como parece. Si te pones en una semana o menos ya tienes tu API funcionando.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me pondré ahora mismo con ello, a ver si lo consigo, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día Lucia, por lo que entendí de lo redactado quieres a través de un formulario obtener datos de una base de datos que esta en otro servidor distinto al de la web.

Te recomendaría crear una `Api` en el servidor donde se encuentran los datos que necesitas recuperar con `PHP` y luego desde el formulario realizar una petición y podrás obtener los datos que necesites.

Otra forma seria crear un archivo `php` en donde desarrollas la conexión con la base de datos y podrías crear unos métodos donde obtienes los datos que necesites y colocar un **header** `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` que servirá para darte permisos y consultarlos desde la web en el otro servido vía `Ajax` con `javascript`.

Básicamente desde la web a través de `ajax` consultas a la **url** del otro servidor donde esta tu archivo `php` programado y consultas los datos por ejemplo:

"https://tu-web/tu-archivo-php.php?clave=valor

Ejemplo:

https://tu-web.com/datos_clientes.php?month=2&day=24&year=2019&category=7

(ejemplo de seteo de tu archivo `php`)

Espero que sea de gran ayuda.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias. Probaré primero otra vez con el nombre del equipo del servidor de la base de datos, y luego con su ip, ya que están en la misma red. Luego probaré a investigar sobre cómo crear la api que me has sugerido

Comment: perfecto lucia, me parece que con la **ip** te funcionara, un placer ayudarte.

Comment: La verdad es que no sé ni por dónde empezar a buscar, a ver si puedes ayudarme...
En este caso, quiero que los datos del formulario, vayan a la base de datos, y desde la base de datos poder mirar las respuestas recogidas.
Conseguí milagrosamente crear el código PHP, ya que es la primera vez que toco algo de programación aparte de html, y me costó varios días conseguir que funcionase.
Nunca escuché hablar de una API y no sé ni lo que es, si no es mucho problema y puedes guiarme un poco...
Muchas gracias y perdona las molestias.

Comment: Lucia, cree otra respuesta que quizás pueda ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Lucia, te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como podría ser la solución que necesitas.
espero que te sea de gran ayuda.

Formulario HTML con AJAX javascript con JQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" method="post" action="#" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre">
        <label>Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido">
        <button type="submit" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
        <span id="resultado"></span>
    </form>

    <!-- Jquery - Ajax -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function() {
            $("form").on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                /* Act on the event */
                var datos = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "get_clientes.php",
                  data: datos,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(data){
                    $("#resultado").empty();
                    $("#resultado").text(data);
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                  {
                    $("#resultado").empty();
                    $("#resultado").text('Ocurrio un error: '+xhr.status+' - '+thrownError);
                  }
                });
            });     
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Archivo db.php**
Configuraciones para la conexión a la base de datos Mysqli.

```
<?php
function getConn(){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'toor';
    $pass = 'toor';
    $db = 'test';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    return $mysqli;
}
?>
```

**Archivo get_clientes.php**
Guardara los datos del cliente en la base de datos.

```
<?php
    //cabecera para poder recibir peticiones desde otra ip o dominio
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    //obtenemos el archivo db.php con la configuracion de la base de datos.
    require_once 'db.php';    

    //comprobamos que los campos esten completos (en caso de ser necesario)
    if (!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido'])) 
    {
        //instanciamos la conexion a base de datos
        $mysqli = getConn();
        $add = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, apellido) VALUES (?, ?)");
        //parametros para insertar
        $add->bind_param("ss", $_POST['nombre'], $_POST['apellido']);
        //ejecutamos la insercion 
        if ($add->execute()) 
        {
            //success
            echo "Los datos se guardaron correctamente.";
        }
        else
        {
            //error
            echo "Error al guardar los datos.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "debe completar los campos.";
    }
?>
```